# Проверить, входят ли 2 строчки через not in python

Tags: python

Хочу сделать проверку сразу 2 строчек:

```
if 'excel','spreadsheet' not in content_type:
```

Как это сделать красиво на питоне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
if 'excel' not in content_type and 'spreadsheet' not in content_type:
```

Comment: Это не равнозначные условия. При выносе `not` за скобки `and` в скобках меняется на `or` (и наоборот). Почитайте про [законы Де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Законы_де_Моргана).

Comment: 1-ый вариант подошёл.

Comment: @insolor да, пожалуй вы правы. Оставлю первый вариант :)

Answer (score 6):

Если есть список строк, ни одна из которых не должна присутствовать в `content_type`, то можно использовать такое условие:

```
exclusions = ['excel', 'spreadsheet']

if all(word not in content_type for word in exclusions):
    pass
```

Функция `all` проверяет, что ей передана последовательность состоящая только из истинных элементов (`bool(x) == True`).

В данном случае берется по одному слову из списка `exclusions`, и для каждого проверяется что этого слова нет в `content_type`. Дальше, если все проверки дали результат `True`, то функция `all` вернет `True`. Если хотя бы одно `False`, то `all` вернет `False`.